# how to calculate time difference based on 2 fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am familiar to simple mongodb queries but this one is a bit complex for me. Here, what I am trying to achieve is on the basis of `jsonObject.callID` and `jsonObject.mobile` fields I have to calculate time difference of `jsonObject.timestamp`. For example in below sample documents, `jsonObject.callID` and `mobile` will remain same for `jsonObject.action` `start` and `end`. So based on `jsonObject.callID` and `jsonObject.mobile`, I have to subtract the `jsonObject.timestamp`. `jsonObject.callId` will be same for two interval actions i.e. `start` and `end` with their same `jsonObject.mobile` numbers.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5df9bc5ee5e7251030535df5"),
        "_class" : "com.abc.mongo.docs.IvrMongoLog",
        "jsonObject" : {
                "mode" : "ivr",
                "callID" : "33333",
                "callee" : "128",
                "action" : "end",
                "mobile" : "218924535466",
                "timestamp" : "2019-12-18  16:18:12"
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5df9bc3de5e7251030535df4"),
        "_class" : "com.abc.mongo.docs.IvrMongoLog",
        "jsonObject" : {
                "mode" : "ivr",
                "callID" : "33333",
                "callee" : "128",
                "action" : "start",
                "mobile" : "218924535466",
                "timestamp" : "2019-12-18  16:12:11"
        }
}
```

So I am trying to achieve a output like below:

```
 {
                "callee" : "128",
                "mobile" : "218924535466",
                "callID" : "33333",
                "minutes_of_call" : "6" // difference of "2019-12-18  16:18:12" - "2019-12-18  16:12:11"
        }
```

subsequently I need such results for next documents...

Kindly assist.

Comment: Please timestamp save in mongodb format like that  2014-01-01T08:15:39.736Z after that we can do it

Comment: ok..I will do that.. next?

Comment: ok, Please give me 5 minutes

Comment: Please share actual data with time format of mongodb at jsoneditor online

Comment: how do I give you mongo documents on jsoneditor online

Comment: use https://jsoneditoronline.org/  and save online , share link with me

Comment: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=98c2fe7fc4364b5ca2f34e37132e42f1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204483/discussion-between-mahesh-bhatnagar-and-jpg).